# blackberry suporetd telugu font

Tags: blackberry, fonts, truetype

I'm checking this condition to load a font:

```
  if (FontManager.getInstance().load("/res/gautami.ttf", "MyFont", FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT) == FontManager.SUCCESS)
     try {
         FontFamily typeface = FontFamily.forName("MyFont");
         Font myFont = typeface.getFont(Font.PLAIN, 50);
         helloWorld.setFont(myFont); 
     }
```

My code does not enter into the loop.

Even I tried: vemana2000, pothana, abteluhu, akaher etc....
I'm getting [`NullPointerException`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)

Comment: Are you trying on device or simulator ? try both and update the question with your test results

Comment: Where is the loop that you mentioned in your question ?

Comment: I tried in device also but same boxes are displaying

Comment: Where is the loop that you mentioned in your question ?

Comment: sorry bhai there is no loop......plz give me some more suggestions

Comment: Which version of SDK are you using ? and please be sure you are following this url exactly: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17971/Load_and_use_a_custom_font_899948_11.jsp . Also which line throws the exception ? you may debug (step by step) to detect which line causes the exception, this will give me more details to help you

Comment: What is the size of your TTF file font? It must not be larger than 60KB (source: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Custom_fonts_899947_11.jsp). So what is your file size ?

Comment: (FontManager.getInstance().load("/res/gautami.ttf", "MyFont", FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT)      at this line my code suspends.

Comment: and I'm using SHREE940.ttf file & its size is below 60KB

Comment: I'm using blackberry plugin 1.5.0 version

Comment: Yessssssss.......Bhai I got it........TQ 4r ur guidence.....

Comment: If this solves the issue, please mark my next answer up and set it as solution ! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your font file size should be less than 60KB